# What is an algebra for an algebraic theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monads

Definition 1.1 of [Algebraic Theories](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/algebraic-theories/D6055CE69E527DE387FB557DA7264E80) says an algebraic theory is a small category $\mathcal{T}$ with finite products, and an algebra for theory $\mathcal{T}$ is a product preserving functor $A$ from $\mathcal{T}$ to $\text{Set}.$

My question is, how is this concept related to the idea of an [algebra over an endofunctor](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/algebra+for+an+endofunctor) or of an [algebra over a monad](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/algebra+over+a+monad) ?

For example, I am wondering if there is a connection with some [Eilenberg-Moore categories](https://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/Eilenberg-Moore+category).

Comment: Under the correspondence between algebraic theories and finitary monads on Set, an algebra for an algebraic theory is precisely an algebra for the corresponding monad (and vice versa). Hence, the category of finite-product preserving functors into Set is equivalent to the Eilenberg–Moore category.